# VBA or Excel maximum value from a list

Tags: excel, vba, list, max

First of all, sorry if this have been asked before but I haven´t found anything that could address my issue.

I have the following data:

```
System  | Priority
------------------
System1 | 3
------------------
System2 | 4
------------------
System3 | 5
------------------
System1 | 6
------------------
System2 | 2
------------------
System3 | 9
------------------
```

And I want to create this new column:

```
System  | Priority | MaximumPriority
------------------------------------
System1 | 3        | 6
------------------------------------
System2 | 4        | 4
------------------------------------
System3 | 5        | 9
------------------------------------
System1 | 6        | 6
------------------------------------
System2 | 2        | 4
------------------------------------
System3 | 9        | 9
------------------------------------
```

Essentially, in my new column, I need to obtain the maximum priority (column B) for each specific system (column A).

Any ideas??

Many thanks :)

Update:

[note excel formulas are in Spanish, so MAX(SI = MAX(IF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpksr.png)

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: In my new column, I need to obtain the maximum priority (column B) for each specific system. This is part of a more complex code, where I will remove duplicates and calculate other stuff with my systems.

Comment: You shouldn't append a new DB colum, because the data from it is already there. What you want is that you are able to calculate the **max value** of `Priority` for a given `System`

Comment: That would be helpful as well, but I have developed my code in a way that I am going to need that new column with the max value of Priority for the system in column A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways you could do it:

In an array formula (enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter):
`{=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$7=$A2,$B$2:$B$7))}`
(curly brackets automatically appear when entered correctly).

If you have Excel 2016 (I don't have it, but I think the syntax is correct):
`=MAXIFS($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7,$A2)`
*NOTE:* This feature is only available if you have an Office 365 subscription.

Also, make sure calculation is set to `Automatic` otherwise all cells will show the value from the first cell you entered the formula in.

Comment: One point - `MAXIFS` isn't available with all copies of Excel 2016, it's only available if you have an [Office 365 subscription](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MAXIFS-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883).

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K.  Didn't know that - my work has only just _upgraded_ to Excel 2010.

Comment: I got excited when I saw you saying that it is available in Excel 2016, because I recently got that on my personal computer.  I immediately went to try playing with all the new features that I had forgotten that I would now have.  Then I found out that none of them were there.  So I checked the MAXIFS webpage and got very depressed when I realised I would have to pay Microsoft constant yearly payments if I wanted to make use of it.  I guess I can live without it.

Comment: Hi Darren, thanks for your comments 
However, after trying with first option (I don´t have Excel 2016) the new column only showed the maximum value of priority, which is 9, in all rows.

Comment: That'll probably be because you entered it as a normal formula which will return 9 as the maximum value in the list.  Rather than just `Enter` use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.  You'll know you've done it properly as the formula will get the curly brackets around it.

Comment: I´ve done it, but unfortunately it does not work, I can see the curly brackets but 9 in all rows. 2 questions, do I have to change any setting? when pressing ctrl+shift+enter do I have to select also the rest of the cells where I want the formula to be running or just the first cell?

Comment: Just select the cell where you want the formula to be running and then drag-down as normal.  Selecting all cells will put the same value in all cells - but I was getting 6 rather than 9 when I tried that (the value in the first cell).  The `$A$2:$A$7=$A2` part of the formula should update as you drag it down - `$A$2:$A$7=$A3`, `$A$2:$A$7=$A4`, etc.

Comment: I can see $A being updated to A2, A3, A4 in the formula as I drag it down. however I still see the 9 in all rows... damn it!!

Comment: Something else must be going on there.  Could you update your original question with a screenshot of your data with the array formula showing in the formula bar?

Comment: Darren, screenshot uploaded, please could you check? Many thanks

Comment: It looks fine.  Only other thing I can think of - is calculation set to manual?  Press `F9` to force a calculation, if it all updates then you need to go to _File ~ Options ~ Formulas_ and change the Workbook Calculation.

Comment: Genius, it was because of that ;)! Cheers Darren

Comment: lol, it's always the simple things that trip us up for ages.  I'll update my answer to include that bit. :)